# Android Emulator system app disappears after reboot

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have installed android sdk on Ubuntu 12.04, its working fine, for testing I installed some application like whatsapp,fileexplorer etc, unfortunately after reboot application disappears, in fact emulator shows only default apps, finally after many google search I found some post on system application, and I tried like this

```
 $ adb devices
 List of devices attached 
 emulator-5554  device

 adb root
 adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system
 adb push WhatsApp.apk /system/app/
 adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/WhatsApp.apk
 adb shell mount -o ro,remount /system
 adb reboot
```

Above command installs whatsapp successfully but if I restart emulator again whatsapp disappears. Don't know what to do

Kindly someone share the tricks to success

Answer (score 1):

Emulator use system image of target platform which placed in SDK folder.
I'm not sure, but I think after reboot system partition /system restoring from system image.
Try to install apps, find emulator cache on your host system (in Windows search in %temp% folder by "emulator' key word or by size).
When you find cached image, replace system image in SDK folder (don't forget make a back up).

That's way helped me to install Google Play on emulator.

Sorry for my bad English